# How to prevent loss of lines after saving/scaling Bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, image

After saving bitmaps on disk there's loss of details. The same image can have different dimensions.
If image has an enough dimension, we have a good picture: 
http://prntscr.com/6g5ku0
Else image loses details
http://prntscr.com/6g5i09
Are there any algorithms for quality saving bitmap without loss of details?
I'm using C#.

Comment: You can't save an image with lower resolution but keep all the details, that is quite impossible. When you change the resolution (and by this in this context I mean the number of pixels width and height) you need to do some kind of resampling, either picking out pixels from the original image or calculating new ones. Either way it is impossible to bring over all the pixels, which means detail will be lost.

Comment: It's not the saving part that makes it lose details. It's the scaling when you make the dimensions smaller.

Comment: OK, but may be I can make new image with necessary resolution on the basis of original?

Comment: For this you need to know how thick the thinnest lines you want to preserve are. If the finest detail is 10 pixels wide you can divide each dimension by 10..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is not possible.

However, for some special cases there are ways to workaround the basic rule.

If your images are typical, then you may try this:

Create an overlayed image that consists of the original image draw four times with 1 pixel offsets right and/ or down. Make sure you use the `SourceOverlay` option of the `DrawImage` method.

Now you can half the dimensions without losing any lines.

Of course the basic rule still applies and the workaround can only work if you can live with the loss that happens during the overlay: Here all small (1 pixel) white spaces are being filled with black. No black lines are lost but many white gaps.

If that is acceptable, fine, if not, then the basic rules stands: You can't reduce the size of one pixel in a Bitmap..

Here is an example: First the orginal, then the overlay and finally the reduced image:

[image]

The code is straightforward. The only point to note is that in order to do overlays the background of the image should be transparent. I took a shortcut by setting the color found in pixel `(0,0)` to transparent in the whole image. This will only work if a) that pixel is indeed of the background color and b) the background is **one** color only..

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap("D:\\fineline.png");
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp1;

    Bitmap bmp2 = (Bitmap)bmp1.Clone();
    bmp2.MakeTransparent(bmp2.GetPixel(0, 0));
    Bitmap bmp3 = (Bitmap)bmp2.Clone();
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp3))
    {
        G.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        G.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        G.DrawImage(bmp2, 0, 1);
        G.DrawImage(bmp2, 1, 1);
        G.DrawImage(bmp2, 1, 0);
    }
    pictureBox2.Image = bmp3;

    Bitmap bmp4 = new Bitmap(bmp3.Width / 2, bmp3.Height / 2);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp4))
    {
        G.Clear(bmp1.GetPixel(0, 0));
        G.DrawImage(bmp3, 0, 0, bmp4.Width, bmp4.Height);
    }
    pictureBox3.Image = bmp4;

    // do dispose of all bitmaps when no longer needed!!
    bmp2.Dispose(); // in the test the others still sit in the PictureBoxes

}
```

Comment: Make sure you dispose of the Bitmaps when you are done with them!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a Bitmap at a lower resolution it will always be lossy. You need to save it at the original size.

Comment: That is a comment, not an answer!

Comment: In this context I disagree. The answer to this question is "You can't do it".

Comment: How is it not an answer?

Comment: [The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)